# How to remove the margin top from a div with display table-cell?

Tags: html, css

I have to divs with display: table-cell:

```
<div>
    This is table cell
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aa61mLbn/

But the content from the first div has some kind of top margin added by the
display-table. 
I inspected the element and there is not any margin computed, but as you
can see in the jsfiddle, there is some space between the content and the top
of the div. I want to know how to remove that space.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a vertical-align property to your div with a value of "top"

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #7cbaf4;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
div {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #7cbaf4;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #FF6347;
}
```

```html
<div>
    This is table cell
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;  // same effect , but better
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks Scott, I tried inline-block, but the first div doesn't have the same height of the second div

Comment: then you're going to need to adjust vertical-align like the other answers suggest ,  you can also mess with line-height

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align:top;` to `div`:

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

This will force the text to go up. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aa61mLbn/2/